# Patching xConnect, AutomationEngine, IndexWorker configuration

Tags: configuration, xconnect

Is there a way to patch xConnect, AutomationEngine, IndexWorker configuration in a way we do it for sitecore instance?

I.e. configuration that resides in xConnect instance folders:

- \App_data\config\sitecore
- \App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore
- \App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Config\Sitecore

where configuration is xml based rather then .config

Comment: @SitecoreClimber for example patch sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml to set IndexAnonymousContactData=true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to patch xml configuration files in the following way:

1. Create patch config file with the name: *sc.(patch name).xml*
2. Add the actual settings to patch:

e.g. patch *IndexAnonymousContactData* setting

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
        <SearchIndexer>
            <Services>
                <IndexerSettings>
                    <Options>
                        <IndexAnonymousContactData>true</IndexAnonymousContactData>
                    </Options>
                </IndexerSettings>
            </Services>
        </SearchIndexer>
    </XConnect>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

3. Patches are applied in alphabetical order, so the patch file has to reside in a folder that goes after the folder which is being patched, i.e. after *SearchIndexer* folder, for example you could use folder called *SearchIndexer_patch*.

Comment: Finally had a chance to test it. Confirm it works as described. Thanks @grg

Comment: Can you elaborate on sc.(patch name).xml? Should (patch name) match the file you are patching exactly or can it be a custom value?

Comment: @TxRegex seems like it has to be the exact same name